# How to find the complexity of solving a 0-1 second order cone programming?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

I have a 0-1 second order cone (SOC) problem and I need to know the complexity of solving this problem if branch and cut (B&C) method is used?. The way I addressed this question is as following:

The 0-1 SOC problem can be solved using B&C method which has an exponential worst case complexity, i.e., O(2^n). At each node of B&C method, the relaxed problem is a SOC problem which can be solved using an interior point method which has a polynomial-time complexity. However, I do not have an expression for the complexity of the interior point method yet. Assuming this complexity is O(n). Then, I can claim that the complexity of solving the 0-1 problem using B&C method is O(2^n) times O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Do not think so. You are solving n nodes each with complexity O(n). By my calculations it would come out to be O(2^n*n^2).